# How to stretch the elements of Wrap vertically based on available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using Wrap widget to wrap these elements which have dynamic values from api, so I have no control over the height of containers. I'm looking for a way to stretch the containers to take full height of available space based on the container next to them. The screenshot of the issue which I'm facing is attached below for your reference.
**Here is my code:**

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/models/game_pebble.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/models/trail.dart';
import "package:ria/src/services/map_indexed_extension.dart";
import 'multi_answer_media_option.dart';

class MaVideoMineral extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MaVideoMineralState createState() => MaVideoMineralState();
  final Mineral mineral;
  final GamePebble? pebble;
  final Color mainColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;
  final Function onChangeAnswer;

  MaVideoMineral(this.mineral, this.pebble, this.mainColor, this.secondaryColor,
      this.onChangeAnswer);
}

class MaVideoMineralState extends State<MaVideoMineral> {
  List<MineralPropertyValue> answers = [];
  bool valid = true;

  Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    answers = widget.mineral.properties!.first.values!
        .where((answer) => answer.answer == "1")
        .toList();
    valid = widget.mineral.properties!.first.values!
        .any((answer) => answer.answer == "1");

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      widget.onChangeAnswer(answers, valid);
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  _handleSelectOption(option) {
    widget.pebble!.canChangeAnswer == true
        ? setState(
            () {
              var value = option.answer != "1";
              if (value == true) {
                option.answer = "1";
                answers.add(option);
              } else {
                option.answer = null;
                answers.removeWhere((answer) => answer.id == option.id);
              }
              valid = option.answer == "1" ? true : false;
            },
          )
        : setState(() {});
    widget.onChangeAnswer(answers, valid);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10, left: 0, right: 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          widget.mineral.properties?.first.selectLimit != null &&
                  widget.mineral.properties?.first.selectLimit != 0
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${'select'.tr()} ${widget.mineral.properties!.first.selectLimit.toString()} ${widget.mineral.properties!.first.selectLimit == 1 ? 'option'.tr() : 'options'.tr()}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.7),
                          ),
                          // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          // maxLines: 4,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Container(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Wrap(
                    spacing: 10,
                    // alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                    runSpacing: 10,
                    // direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    children:
                        widget.mineral.properties!.first.values!.mapIndexed(
                      (option, index) {
                        return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                          child: MultiAnswerMediaOption(
                            option,
                            index,
                            widget.mainColor,
                            widget.secondaryColor,
                            (value) {
                              _handleSelectOption(value);
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem I'm facing]
The container widget

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/models/trail.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/widgets/answer_option_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/widgets/answer_option_video_player.dart';
import 'package:ria/src/widgets/full_screen_image.dart';

class BadgeDecoration extends Decoration {
  final Color badgeColor;
  final double badgeSize;

  const BadgeDecoration({
    required this.badgeColor,
    required this.badgeSize,
  });

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) =>
      _BadgePainter(badgeColor, badgeSize);
}

class _BadgePainter extends BoxPainter {
  static const double CORNER_RADIUS = 15;
  final Color badgeColor;
  final double badgeSize;

  _BadgePainter(this.badgeColor, this.badgeSize);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(
        offset.dx + configuration.size!.width - badgeSize, offset.dy);
    canvas.drawPath(buildBadgePath(), getBadgePaint());
    canvas.restore();
  }

  Paint getBadgePaint() => Paint()
    ..isAntiAlias = true
    ..color = badgeColor;

  Path buildBadgePath() => Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()
        ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(0, 0, badgeSize, badgeSize,
            topRight: Radius.circular(CORNER_RADIUS))),
      Path()
        ..lineTo(0, badgeSize)
        ..lineTo(badgeSize, badgeSize)
        ..close());
}

class MultiAnswerMediaOption extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MultiAnswerMediaOptionState createState() => MultiAnswerMediaOptionState();
  final MineralPropertyValue option;
  final int index;
  final Color mainColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;
  final Function onClickOption;

  MultiAnswerMediaOption(this.option, this.index, this.mainColor,
      this.secondaryColor, this.onClickOption);
}

class MultiAnswerMediaOptionState extends State<MultiAnswerMediaOption> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<String> alphabets = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H",
    "I",
    "J",
    "K",
    "L",
    "M",
    "N",
    "O",
    "P",
    "Q",
    "R",
    "S",
    "T",
    "U",
    "V",
    "W",
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onClickOption(widget.option);
      },
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
              foregroundDecoration: widget.option.answer == "1"
                  ? BadgeDecoration(
                      badgeColor: widget.mainColor,
                      badgeSize: 60,
                    )
                  : BoxDecoration(),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: widget.option.answer == "1"
                    ? widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.3)
                    : widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(16),
                ),
                // border: Border.all(
                //   color: widget.option.answer == "1"
                //       ? widget.mainColor
                //       : widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                // ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    widget.option.media != null &&
                            widget.option.media!.first.url != null
                        ? widget.option.media!.first.type == "image"
                            ? InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  await showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (_) => FullScreenImage(
                                      true,
                                      url: widget.option.media!.first.url,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 5.0, bottom: 8, right: 3, left: 3),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      widget.option.media!.first.url!),
                                ),
                              )
                            : widget.option.media!.first.type == "video"
                                ? Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 5.0, bottom: 8, right: 3, left: 3),
                                    child:
                                        AnswerOptionVideoPlayer(widget.option),
                                  )
                                : widget.option.media!.first.type == "other"
                                    ? AnswerOptionAudioPlayer(widget.mainColor,
                                        widget.option.media!.first.url)
                                    : Container()
                        : Container(),
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 35,
                          height: 35,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 2,
                              color: widget.option.answer == "1"
                                  ? widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.8)
                                  : widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                            ),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: widget.option.answer == "1"
                                ? widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.8)
                                : widget.mainColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                alphabets[widget.index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: widget.option.answer == "1"
                                      ? widget.secondaryColor
                                      : widget.mainColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                            child: Text(
                              widget.option.value,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: widget.mainColor, fontSize: 18),
                              maxLines: 4000,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            widget.option.answer == "1"
                ? Positioned(
                    top: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/check.svg",
                      height: 18,
                      width: 18,
                      color: widget.secondaryColor,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    width: 25,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue here!

Comment: maybe `CustomMultiChildLayout` will help? the docs say: *"CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets."*

Comment: what do you want to archive for long text?